# InteropServices.COMException in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to submit a workItem to TFS "ONLINE" through a WEB API. It works fine in my local machine but when i upload it to the shared hosting server it's not working.

An error has occurred.

Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DataStoreNative.UpdateMetadata(IntPtr handle, Object rowset, String dbstamp, UInt32& changes) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.Datastore.UpdateMetadata(Object rowset, String dbstamp) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.EndBackendCall(BackendCallData data) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.RefreshCacheInternal(BackendCallData& data) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ITfsTeamProjectCollectionObject.Initialize(TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.InitializeTeamFoundationObject(String fullName, Object instance) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.CreateServiceInstance(Assembly assembly, String fullName) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(Type serviceType) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetServiceT at FeedBackService.Models.TFSManager.AddWorkItem(String title, String description, String imagePath) in e:\Industry\InsightSoft\FeedBack\FeedBackService\FeedBackService\Models\TFSManager.cs:line 249 at FeedBackService.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in e:\Industry\InsightSoft\FeedBack\FeedBackService\FeedBackService\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 28 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c_*DisplayClass13.b*_c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

My code:

> ```
> public void AddWorkItem(string title,string description,string imagePath)
>         {
>             string _myUri = "https://testredrock.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection";
>
>             NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
>             BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);
>
>             TfsClientCredentials credential = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
>             credential.AllowInteractive = false;
>
>             string TFSServerPath = "https://testredrock.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection";
>
>
>
>             using (TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(TFSServerPath), credential))
>             {
>                 CatalogNode catalogNode = tfs.CatalogNode;
>
>                 ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> tpNodes = catalogNode.QueryChildren(
>
>                                 new Guid[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject },
>
>                                 false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);
>
>                 WorkItemStore workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
>                 Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects[project];
>                 WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes[workitemType];
>
>                 // Create the work item. 
>                 WorkItem userStory = new WorkItem(workItemType)
>                 {
>                     // The title is the only required field that does not have a default value. 
>                     // You must set it, or you cannot save the work item. 
>                     Title = title,
>                     Description = "",
>
>
>
>                 };
>
>                 userStory.Fields["Repro Steps"].Value = description;
>
>                 // Save the new user story. 
>                 userStory.Save();
>
>             }
>
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, although I was working on an internal TFS. Clearing the files in:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation\4.0\Cache

where I was connecting to TFS from solved the problem for me.